# Xamarin Mac Agent Connection Error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

[image]

When i am trying to connect Mac i am getting this error when i trying to connect VS2015 is Closed Automatically. How can i solve this problem

Comment: The issue is right there in the error message: the Mac has version 9.1 and your local VS has version 9.8.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error will mean that there is a version mismatch between the Windows System and the Mac. You will want to install the latest stable version of Xamarin on the Mac.

You can do this by opening Xamarin Studio and selecting "Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates". Once the updater appears, you will want to install all updates available.

Once all updates are installed, you should be able to connect.

Thanks!